# Terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

When my app execute the following then i am getting: `terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

```
NSDictionary *temporary = nil;
if(eventName != nil) {
  NSLog(@"nil found -----> ");
  temporary = @{@"eventname": @"OK",
                              @"type": dictionary[@"type"],
                              @"from"  : dictionary[@"from"],
                              @"to"  : dictionary[@"to"]};
}
else {
  NSLog(@"OK no nil found -----> ");
  temporary = @{@"eventname": @"?????",
                              @"type": dictionary[@"type"],
                              @"from"  : dictionary[@"from"],
                              @"to"  : dictionary[@"to"]};
}
```

ERROR:

```
2017-02-18 13:49:26.411903 ios[3645:1360486] [DYMTLInitPlatform] platform initialization successful
2017-02-18 13:49:26.543678 ios[3645:1360413] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled
2017-02-18 13:49:26.544129 ios[3645:1360413] Metal API Validation Enabled
2017-02-18 13:49:26.689675 ios[3645:1360413] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2017-02-18 13:49:26.691524 ios[3645:1360413] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
2017-02-18 13:49:26.998874 ios[3645:1360413] eventName = servers, type = (null), from = (null), to = (null)
2017-02-18 13:49:26.998919 ios[3645:1360413] nil found -----> 
2017-02-18 13:49:26.999137 ios[3645:1360413] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18c9b51b8 0x18b3ec55c 0x18c898eac 0x18c898d1c 0x1000fc2b8 0x1000f92cc 0x1000e58e0 0x18d4c9048 0x18c962b5c 0x18c9624a4 0x18c9600a4 0x18c88e2b8 0x18e342198 0x1928d57fc 0x1928d0534 0x1000a1f48 0x18b8715b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]'

**Your Problem:**

You are trying to insert a `nil` object to your `NSDictionary` `temporary` .

`NSDictionary` crashes if you try to insert `nil` objects. **You can however** insert `NSNull` to it.

**Your solution:**

Do like this for every key you are unsure of , to make it safe from crashing (If its a string, otherwise do equivalent checks):

```
id fromObject = fromString.length ? fromString : [NSNull null];
```

and simply insert `fromObject` into your `NSDictionary`, even if it is `nil`, you will not crash.

```
@"from"  : fromObject,
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear:

> attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]

All values in a dictionary must not be `nil`, but apparently one of the values for keys `type`, `from` or `to` **is** nil, according to the print output even all three are (*eventName = servers, type = (null), from = (null), to = (null)*).